# TBB install something went wrong

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, update

Like another poster I installed tbb 4 over the existing 3 and get the error message something went wrong .... my question is how do I transfer all of my bookmarks settings and add ons from the 3 version to the 4 version please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-40-released

> This release also features an in-browser updater, and a completely reorganized bundle directory structure to make this updater possible. This means that simply extracting a 4.0 Tor Browser over a 3.6.6 Tor Browser will not work.

Do this:

1. Backup your bookmarks from 3.6.6 using the bookmark manager of Firefox.
2. Remove TBB 3.6.6 completely.
3. Unpack TBB 4.0.
4. Start TBB 4.0.
5. Import you bookmarks from the backup file.

Using add-ons other then the ones provided by TBB is not recommended.